# Acceptable Video Size For Social Network With FFMpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, compression, social-networking, video-processing, android-ffmpeg

I'm building a social network on Android and using FFMPeg to compress the videos before uploading them. Videos will have maximum 1 minute of duration.

The original video for test has **87.74Mb 1080x1920**.

Trying to find the middle point between quality and file size I could get to a video size of either **26Mb** with an "meh" quality (which I'm not happy with) or **33.06Mb** with a good quality (scaling the video to 480x852).

***Problems:***

1) It's taking an average of 2min 30sec to compress a 1 minute video!

2) Even 25Mb seems to be too much for a 1 minute video for a social network

***The ask:***

1) Any clue how do Instagram and Facebook do it to compress and upload the same video above within 1 minute!!?? I know they compress it cause the quality is not the same when on Facebook/Instagram but how to they get it done that fast?

2) What would it be an acceptable file size for a 1 minute video on Facebook/Instagram? I'm worried about wasting too much storage for 1 minute videos. Does anyone have any idea about it?

---

I'm searching a lot about FFMpeg commands to get it better and better but it would be easier if I had in mind what I want to achieve.

Comment: 1) Break input into segments - encode in parallel - stitch encoded segments  2) Download a few and check. IIRC, around 1.5 mbps for 720p.

Comment: @Mulvya 
So you suggest to split the video into smaller parts then encode them in parallel (different threads) then put them together again. Is it?

What do you mean by IIRC? is it the output format? I downloaded a video from facebook I uploaded before (200Mb original video) and the downloaded file was only 2Mb!!! But the quality was horrible! Downloading the HD version was 11Mb but still a s*** quality. Both videos were mp4 though.

Comment: @Gyan when you say "break input into segments" should be done in a separate ffmpeg command or within the same command we have to break input and do the parallel encode?  (if possible can you show how the cmd would look like) and can you give more explanation about the second step please? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use UltraFast parameter for maximum Compression.

For me it reduced 90 mb video to 15 mb.

```
ffmpeg -i {videoPath} -c:v libx264 -crf 40 -preset ultrafast {compressedVideoPath}
```